# How to translate ngx-daterangepicker-material (Calendar, DatePicker) components using ngx-translate service

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, ngx-daterangepicker-material

How can I translate the strings in (Calendar, DatePicker) ngx-daterangepicker-material components using ngx-translate service like (days, months...)??

Images:

[image]

NPM Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-daterangepicker-material

Github Repo: https://github.com/fetrarij/ngx-daterangepicker-material